# GraghQL query returning integer instead of object

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I can't figure out why none of my queries are working on my Gatsby projects.

```
   import React from "react"
   import { graphql } from "gatsby"

   const site_info = () => {
     const query = graphql`
       query title {
         allSite {
           edges {
             node {
               siteMetadata {
                  title
               }
             }
           }
         }
       }
     `
     console.log(query)
     return <p>Test</p>
   }

   export default site_info
```

In the console, I'm expecting an object where I can see the title in metadata, however, I'm getting `2641826822`.

I copied the query directly from GraphiQL where I'm seeing the expected result, so not sure why it isn't working here.

Comment: common ... defining query doesn't mean it is run/data fetched/available in next line of code ... basic react/js knowledge

Answer (score 2):

When you query (using a page query as you've provided) some data using GraphQL in a Gatsby schema, your data is stored as a page `prop` (not in the query variable itself), so you need to access to them `props` and iterate through the object until you find your data. An ideal structure data should look something like:

```
const yourPage = ({ data }) => {
  const { title } = data.allSite.edges[0].node.siteMetadata;

  return <Layout>
    <h1>{title}</h1>
  </Layout>;
};

export const yourPageData = graphql`
       query title {
         allSite {
           edges {
             node {
               siteMetadata {
                  title
               }
             }
           }
         }
       }
     `;

export default yourPage;
```

Basically, in the snippet above I'm destructuring `data` as a `prop` (instead of doing `prop.data`) and I do the same with `data.allSite.edges[0].node.siteMetadata` to get the `title`.

I would recommend some documentation reading about [Querying Data in Pages with GraphQL](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/page-query/) before you dive into GraphQL on the rocks.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the Gatsby doc, now it makes more sense how the query is interacting with the object. However, passing in the prop as you've shown above didn't solve my problem. Data is still returning as undefined. Is it possible that I'm missing something in gatsby-config.js? I have the gatsby-source-filesystem plug in configured as well as the siteMetaData object.

Comment: Is the query working in `localhost:8000/___graphql` playground?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting the expected value there